# How beforeScenario and afterScenario works in JBehave

Tags: jbehave

Can someone show examples of how beforeScenario and afterScenario works in JBehave?

I created a class with two methods gearUp with **@BeforeScenario** and tearDown with **@AfterScenario** annotations.

But these methods are never invoked in JBehave.

What extra configurations are needed. Any code examples will help us.

Whereas this simple and neat in Cucumber.

Following is my story file with single step(src/test/resources/storeis):

```
Scenario:  SampleTest

Given I am test
```

Following is my Steps file

```java
public class jbehavetc {

    @Given("I am test")
    public void startOnUrl(String url) {
       System.out.println("I am actual test");
    }
}
```

Following is my Hooks file which contains BeforeScenario and AfterScenario methods

```java
public class Hooks {

    @BeforeScenario
    public void startSystem() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("I am before scenario");
    }

    @AfterScenario
    public void stopSystem() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("I am after scenario");
    }

}
```

To run the above story i created a runner file and wanted to run as JUnit Test(**Correct me this is not the right approach**)

```java
public class JBehaveRunner extends JUnitStory{


    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryLoader(
                new LoadFromClasspath(getClass().getClassLoader()))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(   
                new StoryReporterBuilder()
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withFormats(Format.HTML));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new jbehavetc(), 
            new Hooks());
    }

    public List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(
            CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()),
            Arrays.asList("**/*.story"),
            Arrays.asList(""));
    }

    @Test
    public void run() throws Throwable {
        super.run();
    }
}
```

When i run above runner as JUnit test, nothing is getting executed. How can i run above story? I want Before and After Scenario methods needs to be invoked when i run this runner or story file.

Comment: In the provided example method `storyPaths` will be ignored since `JUnitStory` is extended. Either extend `JUnitStories` or configure story path resolver via `Configuration#useStoryPathResolver`

Answer (score 1):

You should treat class with `@BeforeScenario`/`@AfterScenario` as classes with step implementations: you should register them in your steps factory.

> **BeforeAndAfterSteps.java**

```java
public class BeforeAndAfterSteps {

    @BeforeScenario
    public void beforeScenario() throws Exception {
        // setup
    }

    @AfterScenario
    public void afterScenario() throws Exception {
        // teardown
    }
}
```

> **Example of steps factory configuration**

```java
new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration, new BeforeAndAfterSteps())
```

---

Official JBehave examples:

- Example of the class containing various before/after implementations: [BeforeAfterSteps](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/steps/BeforeAfterSteps.java)
- Examples of this class references and usages:

  - [CoreEmbedder](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/CoreEmbedder.java#L62)
  - [CoreStory](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/CoreStory.java#L100)
  - [CoreStories](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/CoreStories.java#L99)

Comment: Hi VaL, can you please explain me, how to incorporate like Hooks like functionality. How can i run my simple story? Do we have a concept of Runners in JBehave. How to configure this? I have updated my post what i am trying for. Can you please help me.

Comment: @Uday, you can find more info on JUnit-enabled Embeddables here: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/developing-stories.html. Shortly: you can run a single story, if extending `JUnitStory` or can run multiple stories, if extending `JUnitStories`

Answer (score 0):

Following runner file started working for me:

```java
public class JBehaveRunner extends JUnitStories {

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryLoader(
                new LoadFromClasspath(getClass().getClassLoader()))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                new StoryReporterBuilder()
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withFormats(Format.HTML));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new HomePageSteps(), 
            new BaseEngine());
    }

    @Test
    public void run() throws Throwable {
        super.run();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(
            CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()),
            Arrays.asList("**/*.story"),
            Arrays.asList(""));    
    }
}
```

Comment: From the provided example it's not clear what `HomePageSteps` and `BaseEngine` classes contain

Comment: Consider HomePageSteps contains actual stepDefinitions and BaseEngine is have some utility methods which may also have BeforeScenario and AfterScenario methods.